# QTreeWidget fast updating

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am writing a software in Qt (C++) that parses a text file with a huge amount of data (hundred of thousands lines) and then it links every line to a specific frame of a video. Then it plays the video and at the same time it shows in a QTreeWidget the lines of the file related to the frame showed at that time.

So, since the video has 30fps, the software needs to update the QTreeWidget every 30ms, so it has to clear the QTreeWidget and then put the new lines inside it.

However when I face around 100-200 lines per frame the updating is quite fast, but if I have to treat like 1000 lines per frame it becomes really slow and the program eventually crashes.

Is there a way to speed up the updating? The rate of 1000 QTreeWidgetItems every 30ms is too high or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: It is high. Especially if you are creating the items on the heap. It is 33k object/second, probably heap allocated and a lot of virtual function calls... Run a benchmark and you will see the "costly" part of your code...

Comment: Are you really scrolling (effectively) the `QTreeWidget` data 1000 lines every 30ms?  I don't understand how that can possibly be of any use to the user/viewer.  Sorry if I've misunderstood, but I think you should clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve and post some relevant code.

Comment: Yes, in fact is not so useful in the realtime cycle, but when the user pauses the video they can scroll and look at which lines are linked to that frame. Maybe I could find a strategy to update lines instead then clear the treewidget and recompile it.

Comment: So why not only update the treeview when the video stops or the user hits pause? While it is running you can show a placeholder "pause video to see lines" or somesuch.

Comment: I also thought so, but the user need to observe when a particular line changes in order to pause the video at that frame.

Answer (score 0):

You should first disable updating of QTreeWidget:

> MyTreeWidget->setUpdatesEnabled(false);

Then update the items and make tree updating on:

> MyTreeWidget->setUpdatesEnabled(true);

If this does not help a lot, consider using QTreeView with custom data model instead.